# Gridview always add new row when click button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ado.net, updatepanel

I'm write the code which create new row in gridview when click button. The number of rows are created by value in textbox. Ex: When i enter value 2 in textbox, of course two rows will be added, but when i clicked button again, third rows still added. Please check my code here:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVisitor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code_Behind

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int visitors = Convert.ToInt32(txtVisitor.Text);
    AddNewRowToGrid(visitors);
}

private void SetInitialRow()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
    dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    //dr = dt.NewRow();

    //Store the DataTable in ViewState
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
}

private void AddNewRowToGrid(int visitors)
{
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow;
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int rowindex = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < visitors; i++)
            {
                //extract the TextBox values
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDate");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                drCurrentRow = null;
                rowindex++;
            }
            //add new row to DataTable

            //Store the current data to ViewState
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

            //Rebind the Grid with the current data
            Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SetInitialRow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, could you please explain the point of the textbox? I am running your code and if I type in anything, but 2, then it does not add any rows. The reason for that is because you are trying to find the textbox controls via the GridView's rows collection and since there is only one row in the grid to start with, if you type anything higher than 2 then it bombs out after the first loop iteration.

Comment: @Karl What's wrong in my code. Hope you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is problem #1 with your code:

```
for (int i = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i < visitors; i++)
            {
                //extract the TextBox values
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDate");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                drCurrentRow = null;
                rowindex++;
            }
```

you set i to 1
replace it to row count of gridview
tostart from it

Answer (score 0):

Here is problem #1 with your code:

```
//extract the TextBox values
TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDate");
TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
```

This logic is flawed and not even necessary, because when you bind the grid it will iterate through the collection you supply as the `DataSource` and use the `TemplateFields` you defined in the markup to create each row.

The rows are not actually added to the GridView until is bound to a data source, a `DataTable` in your case, like this:

```
Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Step #1 is to remove the `FindControl` lines from your `AddNewRowToGrid` method.

I am not even sure what you are trying to accomplish in your code.

Comment: when i FindControl i'll get error. I think FindControl is good

Comment: Okay, let's come back to `FindControl` in a minute, but what is the deal with the visitors text box and why does that control how many times the loop happens?

Comment: This code work well, but now i want add new row by specify value in textbox.

Comment: @user2494232 - Good luck to you, I have no idea what are you even trying to do. Saying the code works well and then asking somebody to help you fix is quite contradictory. Try explaining what is supposed to be happening and what is actually happening, because I cannot figure out what your intent is with this UI and logic.

Comment: @user2494232 - Just to let you know, the way your `for (int i = 1; i < visitors; i++)` loop is written, you have an off by one error; in other words, when you type 2 into the textbox it is not adding two rows, but rather one because i starts at 1 and then is compared to be less than 2 and goes through the loop, the next iteration 2 is not less than 2 so it stops the loop. This is why I am asking what you are really trying to achieve with this logic.